# nginx dot'n static in django project

Tags: django, nginx, static

After settings nginx in server static has disappeared from the site.
If you work only with gunicorn, all everything is successful.
Command "python manage.py collectstatic " executed :

440 static files copied to '/home/v_n_kich/Project_LAWboard/static'.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen 51.250.71.28;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
                root /home/v_n_kich/Project_LAWboard/;
        }

        location /media/ {
        root /home/v_n_kich/Project_LAWboard/;
        }

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                         document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

sudo less /var/log/nginx/error.log:

```
2023/02/20 22:59:11 [error] 861#861: *14 open() "/home/v_n_kich/Project_LAWboard/static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 
178.71.105.162, server: , request: "GET /static/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "51.250.71.28", referrer: "http://51.250.71.28/auth/signup/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be with permissions. On your /etc/nginx/nginx.conf you can add group and user to nginx:

```
user USER GROUP;
```

And on the cache dir, set permissions to correspond with USER GROUP:

```
chown USER:GROUP /DIR -R
```

And if necessary, change /DIR permissions to 755

Answer (score 0):

Decided

the problem was indeed permissions

I added users 'www-data' to groups

sudo gpasswd -a www-data 'my groupd'

and

sudo systemctl restart nginx

Comment: See how do I write a good answer [answer].